# TFS 2013 MS build error telling The "RegisterAssembly" task failed unexpectedly. System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException has been disconnected

Tags: tfs, msbuild

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (4335): The "RegisterAssembly" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Object '/57c6900a_1a38_4288_86ac_af0884a7a9eb/nr8uotytqldhem8kcafxupiy_4.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

Server stack trace:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.CheckDisconnectedOrCreateWellKnownObject(IMessage msg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.SyncDispatchMessage(IMessage msg)

Have upgraded the build server from MSBUILD 12.0 to MSBUILD 14.0, started observing the above error.

have checked the .Net framework 4.7.2 is installed on the build server, the build succeeds on both the agents sometimes, looking at the Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets file, it says, , what does this mean, what should I be looking at, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since it is caused by the upgrade of msbuild. You can downgrade msbuild back to 12.0, or try using a higher versin of msbuild than 14.0

Comment: Actually, we have added a ASP.net web api(.NET 4.7.2), added to a project which has .Net 3.5 , so, we need MSBUILD 14.0 to build ASP.net WEB API project. Will try upgrading MSBuild to a higher version.

Comment: does this error related to VS 2015 licensing on the build server? i see, vs 2015 is out of license on the build server.

Comment: I donot think it is related to vs 2015 licensing. The pipeline only uses the msbuild.exe on your agent server to build your sln.

Answer (score 0):

> Have upgraded the build server from MSBUILD 12.0 to MSBUILD 14.0, started observing the above error.

Since you have update the MSBuild from `12.0` to `14.0`, please try to build your project/solution with MSBuild task and specify the path of MSBuild.exe on the server in the MSBuild task.

That is because `MSBuild 14.0` was released after TFS 2013, and TFS2013 cannot directly recognize `MSBuild.exe 14.0`. We have to specify the path of the `MSBuild.exe 14.0` when we want to use `MSBuild 14.0` to build our project/solution.

Comment: Have specified the path of MSBuild 14.0 in the Properties of MSBUILD task, it was working, all of a sudden it started erroring out with the above reason.